# How feed iterator of numpy array to tensorflow Estimator/Evaluable

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have an iterator function that yields one batch of features and label as a tuple of numpy arrays.

def batch_iter():
       for ...:
            yield (np_features, np_labels)

and then I try to feed the tensor Estimator like

```
# the cnn_model_fn will print out shapes of various tensor when
# constructing the model
classifier = learn.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/convnet_model")
for train_data, train_labels in batch_iter():
    classifier.fit(
        input_fn=lambda: (tf.constant(train_data), tf.constant(train_labels)),
        steps=1,
        monitors=[logging_hook])
```

The (annotated) log looks like

```
conv1 shape (100, 16, 20, 32)
pool1 shape (100, 8, 10, 32)
conv2 shape (100, 8, 10, 64)
pool2 shape (100, 4, 5, 64)
onehot label shape (100, 5)
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into /tmp/convnet_model/model.ckpt.    # checkpoint is saved in every iteration
INFO:tensorflow:step = 1, loss = 1618.76
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 1618.76.
conv1 shape (100, 16, 20, 32)    # the model_fn is called in every iteration
pool1 shape (100, 8, 10, 32)
conv2 shape (100, 8, 10, 64)
pool2 shape (100, 4, 5, 64)
onehot label shape (100, 5)
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/convnet_model/model.ckpt-1  # checkpoint is restored in every iteration
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 2 into /tmp/convnet_model/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:step = 2, loss = 69370.6
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 69370.6.
conv1 shape (100, 16, 20, 32)
pool1 shape (100, 8, 10, 32)
conv2 shape (100, 8, 10, 64)
pool2 shape (100, 4, 5, 64)
onehot label shape (100, 5)
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/convnet_model/model.ckpt-2
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 3 into /tmp/convnet_model/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:step = 3, loss = 289303.0
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 289303.0.
...
```

The batches are read and losses do go down as the loop iterate. However, it seems the checkpoints are saved and restored in every iteration and the model_fn is called in every iteration. So I feel that's not right.

What's the right way to feed an iterator to Estimator/Evaluable?

Answer (score 1):

in your input_fn you can use `tf.contrib.training.python_input`